# How to insert a value inside a particular array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuetify.js

I am using Vue (`vuetify`) `v-data-table` to show some data, Its working fine, in the same time I am trying to show some data from another api, So I need to know how to push a items inside of a array of object.

```
axiosThis.tableDataFinal[i].push(axiosThis.printsumget[i])
```

I am getting an error `.push is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, Looks like you are trying to perform a push operation on an `object` instead of an `array`. That's the reason it is giving you that error.

Also, As per my understanding. Your API response will give you an array of objects. So instead of using `.push`, You can use [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Another axios api call. Just for a demo purpose I am using mock array here. You can replace it with an actual API response.
    const res = [{
      name: 'Burger',
      calories: 200
    }, {
      name: 'Chocolate Cake',
      calories: 250
    }];
    this.desserts = [...this.desserts, ...res];
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.12/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.12/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```